# Undefined index using foreach with Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, undefined-index

Ok, my long day is catching up with me... I am trying to list out custom post meta fields and keep getting Notice: **Undefined index: related-headline in...** Here is what the array looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [related-headline] => Street Outlaws Turbo Rotary Mazda RX-7 – OKC NoPrep [related-url] => //localhost:3000/street-outlaws-turbo-rotary-mazda-rx-7-okc-noprep/ [related-image_id] => 78055 [related-image] => //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/lucky-to-be-alive-distracted-dri.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [related-headline] => In the Driver’s Seat: Shane vs. The Reaper | Street Outlaws [related-url] => //localhost:3000/in-the-drivers-seat-shane-vs-the-reaper-street-outlaws/ [related-image_id] => 78048 [related-image] => //localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ford-f350-vs-dodge-ram-vs-chevy.jpg ) ) )
```

Here is my code:

```
$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ss-related-posts' );
// print_r($entries);

foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
    $title = '';
    $title = $entry['related-headline'];
    echo $title;
}
```

I know I am missing something simple here so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Look how nested your array is: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ` ; `(array) $entries` -> `(array) $entries[0]`

Comment: I realize that but that's how it's coming back from WP so I need to work with it somehow.

Comment: See the part after the semicolon for the fix ;)

Comment: Tried it but maybe I'm not following you because now I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(array)' (array) (T_ARRAY_CAST)...

Comment: Ah, just remove the array cast, just: `foreach ( $entries[0] as $key => $entry ) {` (Forgot to remove it in my previous comment)

Comment: Change this line: `$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ss-related-posts' );` to this: `$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ss-related-posts' , TRUE);` - the "TRUE" tells it to be a single value, and will reduce one level of your array.

Comment: @Rizier123...that worked. Should have caught that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoeConlin Please don't post the answer in your question. You can answer your own question and after a while(I think 2 days) you can accept it.

Comment: @cale_b, actually ended up adding TRUE. Had that in earlier and not sure when I dropped it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by simply adding `TRUE` to the function call as suggested in the [comments by cale_b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539118/undefined-index-using-foreach-with-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment56820708_34539118):

```
$entries = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ss-related-posts', TRUE );

foreach ( (array) $entries as $key => $entry ) {
    $title = $url = $img = "";
    $title = $entry['related-headline'];
    $url = $entry['related-url'];
    $img = $entry['related-image'];

    echo $title . "<br>" . $url . "<br>" . $img . "<br>";
}
```